# php code for displaying relational tables

Tags: php, html

This code is running, this is the member page after a member login with their account number and password this page will show with correspondent details about their account.
Now I want to add the fields from another table here. 
My first table is "member" then I created another which is "account" I put relation to the mem_id field of both table in my database in phpmyadmin. 
Now my problem is how to display the relation table in the this page. when a member login with their account number automatically both field in the relational table will display here.

```
<?php  
require_once('connection.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where mem_id='$id'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$fname=$row3['fname'];
$lname=$row3['lname'];
$address=$row3['address'];
$contact=$row3['contact'];
$picture=$row3['picture'];
$gender=$row3['gender'];
}
?>
</h2>
</span>
<table width="597" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="26" colspan="2" class="style11"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="166" rowspan="5" class="style11"><div align="left"><img src="style/LOGO  
GRAY.jpg" alt="no image found"" width="129" height="129" border="1" "<?php echo 
$picture ?>/></div></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">First Name:</div>    
</td>
    <td width="297" valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo 
$fname ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Last Name:</div></td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $lname ?></span>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Gender:</div></td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $gender ?></span> 
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Address:</div></td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $address ?>
</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="42" valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Contact No.: </div> 
</td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $contact ?>
</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
        <!--<?php echo $power ?> -->
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a data base

Comment: phpmyadmin is the administration of MySQL. I created my database here.

Comment: phpmyadmin has nothing to do with the question and should not be in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` the other table. Try this query:

`SELECT mem.*, det.* FROM members AS mem LEFT JOIN details AS det ON details.mem_id = members.mem_id WHERE mem_id = {$id};`

1. Select which fields you want to retrieve, using their prefixes you specify later.
2. Select the base table, giving its fields a prefix.
3. Perform the join, specifying the other table the same way.
4. Specify the relationship between fields and how the other table should be joined. In this case it's where the member IDs are the same.
5. Profit. :)

When you loop through the resulting data, you can reference the new fields just like any other field, because the data is joined together.

Here's [a simple tutorial I found on Google](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) and the [technical reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Your best bet is to play with it yourself. That way you'll learn along the way. :)

Comment: Yes, you're selecting all fields with `*` within the `members` table that we assigned to `mem`. Same for details as `det`.

Comment: No worries. If this works for you, please mark my answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: SELECT member.*, account.* FROM member, account WHERE member.mem_id = account.mem_id' got the correct one. thanks for the link of the tutorial

Comment: That looks wrong. Also why did you mark the other answer as the correct answer?

Comment: it display the two relational tables

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LEFT join in order to display the relevant data of the member.
Hope following tutorial will help you to understand the basics.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm